# How to find UIView with accessibilityIdentifier in UITests Target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to find a `UIView` element with **navigationBar** `accessibilityIdentifier` in test target in order to check the `isEnabled` state.

Have tried the different solutions, but couldn't find the needed one.
Is there a way to achieve what a want?

Tried this solution: `application.groups.matching(identifier: "navigationBar")` - doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

Regular views can be queried using `otherElements`.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.otherElements["navigationBar"]
```